# JQuery mCustomScrollbar autoScrollOnFocus

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, recaptcha, mcustomscrollbar

I have contact form with reCaptcha and using jQuery mCustomScrollbar plugin.

Problem : **When I click on / focus on reCaptcha field, the page scrolls automatically to top of the div.**

See [Demo on Jsffidle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bXGNq/4/show/light/), [Code on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/bXGNq/4/)

*note : if mscrollbar isn't working on jsfiddle, that is issue calling js and css from malihu site.*

```
$(".scroller-back").mCustomScrollbar({
   advanced:{
     updateOnContentResize: true
   }           
});
```

Using `autoScrollOnFocus: false`

> Auto-scrolling on elements that have focus (e.g. scrollbar
>   automatically scrolls-to form textfields when the TAB key is pressed),
>   values: true, false.

```
$(".scroller-back").mCustomScrollbar({
   advanced:{
     autoScrollOnFocus: false,
     updateOnContentResize: true
   }           
});
```

It's working for all fields focus not auto scroll, **how can I fix this issue without using `autoScrollOnFocus: false`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved**

I'm using `focus()` function and mCustomScrollbar function `scrollTo`

```
$("#recaptcha_response_field").focus(function() {
  $(".scroller-back").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",this);
});
```

<kbd>[Code on Jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/bXGNq/5/)</kbd>

When the cursor has focus on recaptcha text field, the scroll will scrolling to on a line with recaptcha text field (scroll to self). But it's doesn't work when we use the tab key. I have tried with alert

```
$('#recaptcha_response_field').focus(function() {
  alert('Handler for .focus() called.');
});
```

Updated

I'm using scrollTo with target id's submit button.

```
var a=Recaptcha.$("recaptcha_response_field");

$(a).focus(function() {
  $(".scroller-back").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","#submit_button");
});
```

<kbd>[Code on Jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/bXGNq/6/)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".scroller-back").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", $("#yourdiv"));
```

Comment: Since this is a really old question and an answer was accepted years ago with way more context, I suggest you delete this answer.